# Java lazy instantation using inversion of control container

Tags: java, dependency-injection, lazy-loading, containers, ioc-container

I have this container:

```
public class DIContainer {
    protected static DIContainer instance;
    protected Hashtable<Class<?>, Class<?>> classMap;

    protected DIContainer(){
        this.classMap = new Hashtable<Class<?>, Class<?>>();
    }

    public static DIContainer getInstance(){
        if (DIContainer.instance == null)
            DIContainer.instance = new DIContainer();
        return DIContainer.instance;
    }

    public void regClass(Class<?> interf, Class<?> classToReg){
        this.classMap.put(interf, classToReg);
    }

    public Object create(Class<?> interf, boolean lazy) throws Exception{
        if(!this.classMap.containsKey(interf))
            throw new Exception("No such class registered with "+interf.getName()+" interface");
        else if(lazy == false)
            return this.classMap.get(interf).newInstance();
        else
            return this.classMap.get(interf);

    }
}
```

And I need to lazy create an object, if lazy creation option is chosen (so it would create some sub-object that would implement same interface). So when first method would be called for that sub-object, it would instantiate 'real' object. How could I do it as I don't know exact method that would be used? How can I check for if any method was called for that object?

Now I only tried this as lazy creation as you can see:
`return this.classMap.get(interf);`

But it gives me an error: `java.lang.ClassCastException`
Do I need some other method to check if any call was made to that sub-object, because after creation is done, I will be out of 'create' method and when method will be called I need to check it somehow?

Here are my test interface and it's implementation class:

```
public interface Interface1 {
    public String getName();
    public void setName(String name);
}

public class Class1 implements Interface1{
    String name;
    Class1(){}

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


}
```

And this is how I test it:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        DIContainer dic = DIContainer.getInstance();
        dic.regClass(Interface1.class, Class1.class);
        Interface1 t1 = (Interface1) dic.create(Interface1.class, true);
```

P.S. If I set lazy creation to false, then it works.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the line `return this.classMap.get(interf);` returns a `Class` object, which you previously put inside the map with the `this.classMap.put(interf, classToReg)` line. The `Class` object definitely cannot be cast to the `Interface1` interface, as it does not implement it, which results in the `ClassCastException`.

What you actually need is to return a kind of a wrapper that implements the `Interface1` interface and wraps the lazily instantiated class. When any of the interface's method is called, the wrapper instantiates the actual object and delegates the call.

If you want to lazy-init an arbitrary class, the most straight forward option would be to use Java's [dynamic proxy](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076233/java-se/explore-the-dynamic-proxy-api.html).